# TexStudio macro

Tags: macros, texstudio

I have been a texstudio user for quite some time now and recently I have started using macros but I haven't been able to figure out how to define something that does the following:

I start to write a sentence and when I reach the end and write the full stop sign `.` I would like to automatically insert a space caracter   and then a CR (enter press) to move the cursor on the next line and start again.

I have been writing my documents like this because it is easier for me keep track of the text. 
I am not sure if such a macro is possible or if it is, it will break functionality in other places. I imagine that this macro must be active outside math, figure or table environments.

Cheers

Comment: How do you treat abbreviations?

Comment: I would imagine that for those cases I would have to delete the new line and get back to the line where the abbreviated word appeared. I didn't think about abbreviations! I just thought that a macro to automatically take me to a new line would be cool and work well with my workflow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Choose `Macros -> Edit macros` from the menu. Click `add`, enter some name and abbreviation of choice. Type `\.` under trigger, and a dot, a space, and a carriage return under `latex content` (see screenshot). I just tested that it works.

[image]

Edit: to suppress the behaviour in math mode, we can add another macro defined only in math mode that just inserts a dot when a dot is typed:

[image]

Although it is not self-evident that this should be so, the math mode macro seems to take precedence over the generic one, which produces the desired behaviour - dot augmented by space and new line in text mode, no change in math mode.

Comment: It works! but unfortunately it works everywhere. is there a way to disable it automatically inside math environment for example? [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158845/define-a-texstudio-keyboard-shortcut-macro-that-activates-only-in-math-mode) example activates the macro only inside a math environment. Can it be made to do the reverse in my case? I don't really understand the syntax.

Comment: See edited answer.

Comment: Perfect! I will accept this as the answer to this problem! Thank you!