# How to get TexStudio to recognise user defined math environments

Tags: macros, texstudio

This problem has been bugging me for ages, and I haven't been able to fix it. When writing papers, I like to use `\[ \]` rather than `\begin{equation} \end{equation}`. Similarly, for aligned equations, I have defined the following environment:

`\def\<#1\>{\begin{align}#1\end{align}}`

The command works fine, and compiles in TexStudio without issue. However, all code inside of `\< \>` is highlighted red as TexStudio does not recognise it as a math environment. How can I amend this?

Comment: Hi @tomasliam and welcome to TeX-SE. Normally I define my own commands with `\newcommand`. When I define them locally, TeXstudio always recognize them. When I define them in an own package, I need a `.cwl`file so that the `\newcommand`s are recognized. I don't use `\def`, [check this] (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/655/140133) except when it is the only option. Personally, I would not suggest creating a command to encapsulate an environment. Environments are well recognizable in TeXstudio, simple to identify and the default shortcut `Ctrl + E` is very useful.

Comment: Yeah most of my commands I define with \newcommand and there isn't an issue. However, I cannot define environments with \newcommand, and require \def. Hmmm... I understand your point, and might go back to just using the long form, I just use align environments so often I would like a simpler version. I did not know of that shortcut, I'll give it a go.

Comment: Oh I see, you may try [newenvironment](https://pt.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Environments), [newtheorem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64931/using-newtheorem) (needs amsthm).
Another VERY good idea to speed up the writing process is to create [TeXstudio macros](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/384517/140133), I really enjoy them (I have macros for predefined blocks of syntax to figures, tables, equations, listings, headers). It is faster and keep the basic syntax neat and tidy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\def\<#1\>{\begin{align}#1\end{align}}
% ==========
\def\bla#1{
    \begin{align}
        \textrm{POTATO: }{#1}
    \end{align}
}
% ==========
\begin{document}
\<x = 2\>
\bla{x = 2}
Text.

\bla{x = 4}

Text.
\bla{x = 6}
\begin{align}\label{eq:A}
x = 2 \\
x = 4 \\
x = 6
\end{align}

\bla{\label{eq:B} x = 8}
%\bla{\label{eq:C} x = 8 \\ x = 10}

\eqref{eq:A}, \eqref{eq:B}. % \eqref{eq:C}.
\end{document}
```

When you define a name for your newcommand, it will be recognized at TeXstudio.

[image]

autocompletion/autosuggestion works nice.

[image]

and, as you said in the question, it works

[image]
[image]

On the other hand, if you keep environments, you keep some useful tools and flexibility.

[image]

It shrinks. (*And I personally love it*).

[image]

It also applies for personal commands with more than one line

[image]

But, if you don't think carefully (*As I did when trying to recreating the situation*) you might have more headaches in the future than you expected.

[image]

Oh... and don't get me wrong, I really like to create my own commands

[image]

When customizing, you should really try to find a balance (*trade-off*) between flexibility, readability, usability and organization (*and a setup that is a dream for someone might the a nightmare for someone else*). The overall suggestion is to look for good practices.